# Can I have my fixed button remain at a fixed size when zooming in mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

> <sub>None of the questions on the subject has any real answer (I've
>   seen one that says "Just stop the zoom altogether!" and the other that
>   says "Set the width!" (which isn't the case))</sub>

I have a web application that's supposed to work on mobile (Mobile Chrome only is enough). Pinch-to-zoom is a must-have feature.

It all works well, except for the control buttons I have. Standard buttons, fixed position at the bottom left of the page.

When I pinch-to-zoom, those buttons, while remain on bottom left, grow along with the zoom.

Is it possible to have those buttons not grow by zoom somehow?

Comment: can you describe the app? is it an app with UI based on html or a native android or ios app?

Comment: @ManZzup: Sorry, that wasn't clear of me. It's a web application viewed in a browser. I edited.

Comment: You can set width and height as percent. Then it will always be the same size relative to the browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a potential fix and good read if you are running into this problem.

Here is the website, [css fixed position](http://dbushell.com/2013/09/10/css-fixed-positioning-and-mobile-zoom/).

> **How my prototype works**
>
> What I’m doing is calculating the zoom level (poorly) with JavaScript
>   and then applying CSS transforms to scale the fixed element back down
>   to normal size. As you might expect there is no smooth transition
>   during zoom. There are a whole host of bugs and edge cases. I’ve not
>   even attempted cross browser support (hence no code).

This does not seem to provide a script but it gives you the idea of what to do and how to accomplish it.

Another link on this site seems to have a bunch of great info about your problem, more of a proposal.

Here is the website, [position: device-fixed;](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html)

The only other option I currently know of is disabling zoom. This is not the best approach but is what I currently do if a mobile design needs a fixed header. This will prevent the user from zooming which will then prevent the element to be affected.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: @Danko It does seem like a rather interesting idea and makes me want to try it out on a responsive web site I have been working on.

Comment: Unfortunately, pinch-to-zoom is a must-have feature, like I said. I cannot disable it. I'll try the other links you've posted, thanks :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I just put that in at the end as the only other option I currently know of. The first link should give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: Yep @JoshPowell let me know when you apply that on your site :D

Comment: @Danko Will do! It may be a while since that is not a concern to my client but that is what time at home is for. :D

Comment: I just test with my iPad, it seems not work on iPad Chrome. When zooming the page, no js trigger worked. I guess pinch-to-zoom doesn't work like the way we zoom pages on desktop browsers.

Comment: @FredWu: You could try capturing touchstart/touchmove events on the window. But even that seems difficult